# Disabling screen record protection for specific app using adb

Tags: adb, security, screen, video-recording

I need to record the screen of an specific app that won't let me do for security reasons. Generally I'd use AZ Screen Recorder but it appears black in this app.

I know it's possible to install some things or plug into the computer to record, but is there a way to disable this record protection on the specific app using adb? Maybe change a flag or something?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. Modify the app removing the screenshot protection. However this is not that simple, as the protection is not application-wide but can be set for every activity (screen in the app) individually. Furthermore the protection can be set using the layout definition (xml in the resource) and/or using Java code ([FLAG_SECURE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406316/150978)). Both could be accomplished using [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to decompile, modify, recompile, and sign the app - but this requires a lot of knowledge.
2. Use a rooted device and a screen recorder that can make use of root permissions. Usually this bypasses the screenshot protection.